# Alignment of columns of nested tables (tabularx)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I want to nest 2 `tabularx` tables: the columns of the "inside" table belong to a column of the "outside" table and therefore shall be indented and have a vertical line on their side.

I tried to do that with the following MWE, but I wish that the second column of the inserted table would be aligned with the "outside" table, so **h and j shall be horizontally aligned with b and d**.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm} X}
\hline
a & b\\
c & d\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\quad}|l}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm} X}
g & h \\
i & j \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
}\\
e & f \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to achieve what you're trying to get, but I think the easiest solution is to reduce the width of the `p` column in the "inner" tabularx group by the combined widths of `\quad` (1 em) and `\tabcolsep`. The following MWE does this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm} X}
\hline
a & b\\    c & d\\    \multicolumn{2}{@{\quad}|l}{
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm-1em-\tabcolsep} X}
         g & h \\             i & j \\          \end{tabularx}
   \end{minipage} }\\    e & f \\    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the width of the first column in your "inner `tabularx`" to accommodate for the `tabular` column separation as well as your indentation using `\quad`. This length arithmetic is made possible by the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm} X}
  \hline
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{\quad}|l}{
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{3cm-\widthof{\quad}-\tabcolsep} X}
        g & h \\
        i & j \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
  }\\
  e & f \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

However, you'll notice that LaTeX gives some "Overfull hbox" warnings. Since you only have 2 columns in your `tabularx`, I would suggest calculating the `X` column instead - using a similar method as above - and making it a paragraph `p{<len>}` column to fix exactly within the `\textwidth` (or `\linewidth`).